# How to monitor developers work data in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I am working on my bachelor thesis (this is my first research project) and trying to evaluate different possibilites to monitor a developers work during a day, aggregate it and illustrate it later. For this purpose, I defined some metrics, I want to measure (they might change over time and there might come more).

My questions are related to the  monitors. To start, I have decided to monitor the developers work (only) within Eclipse (and add a TFS implementation later):

- **Work Items**: I want to know how many work items the developer solved, edited and created. If possible, I want to access the data from MyLin, because multiple different task/bug-trackers can be used (Bugzilla, Mantis, etc.). Unfortunately, I am not sure, if this is possible somehow?
- **IDE-stuff**: (To start), I want to count the number of selects and edits in the code and probably also the number of clicks a developer made within the IDE. I read, that I can create listeners on Eclipse and get the data. Is this right and does anyone know a nice tutorial on that topic?
- **Source Code Management**: To track a developers work, I need to get the developers source code changes (commits). For SVN, GIT and CVS, there are multiple APIs, which I may access with Java or also via webrequests. But before I start that, I wanted to ask you, if someone knows a plug-in or something where I can access the commits from different version control systems? What is the easiest way to do something like that?

I also have a couple of other things, I am going to measure... My aim is to aggregate the data within an Eclipse plugin and then send it the server for the visualisation.

I am not necessarily looking for fully implemented solutions, but more for hints, tutorials, tips, your opinions and probably also questions and propositions!

thank you!

Comment: *"but more for hints,"*  1) Would it count if it was the same item done 100 times? (created, edited, deleted then recreated..) 2) It would take an hour or so to write an app. using the `Robot` to do that while I am on breaks and at lunch.  3)  See 1, but throw the robot into the mix to automate it. *"tutorials, tips, your opinions.."*  My opinion is that those developers subjected to such inane metrics will waste time figuring out how to get around them.   Then their 'productivity' will rise considerably.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would imagine the client/manager would be able to tell if the same work was repeated 100 times. Some of the metrics the OP is trying to report on are available in some widely used CI systems. I don't necessarily think reporting these metrics is a particularly nefarious activity that developers will attempt to circumvent.

Comment: @munyengm *"I would imagine the client/manager would be able to tell if the same work was repeated 100 times."*  If you think a manager can determine that from an aggregate graph, you have a vivid imagination.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson What I meant was that if a manager assigned the developer 5 tasks and the metrics reported 100 tasks completed – a competent manager should smell a rat. Or if 100 tasks were completed but the end result was vapourware the manager should become suspicious. Metrics are only as good as the individual evaluating and interpreting those metrics. Whether making those metrics available in the first place is a good thing or not is probably open to debate :-).

Comment: Do you really feel like the whole approach has any value? At the end of the day, the work _results_ are what counts, not whether it took me 500 clicks and 20 commits or some other arbitrary number. I would quit a company doing such investigations, besides that it is completely illegal here in Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out with rabbit plugins for eclipse to track the time spent on it. It has different trackers to record the statistics about different commands executed, duration of the  perspective or views used, time spent on editors etc.. And this plugins has a view to see all the statistics collected. have a look at the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Some of the metrics you want are produced by Hudson/Jenkins plugins as a starting point you could look at how those plugins produce those metrics. Same applies for the Eclipse metrics find existing plugins which manipulate or consume some of the metrics you want and use that as a starting point - since most of them are OpenSource.